# Determine if ranges overlap

Tags: java, c, math, boolean

Given two events with integer start and end times, E1 = (s1, e1), E2 = (s2, e2), implement a quick boolean check to see if the events overlap.

I have the solution, but I'm curious to see what others come up with.

EDIT: OK, here's my solution:

```
e1 > s2 || (s1 > s2 && e2 < s1)
```

Comment: "I have the solution" - yeah, right. This sounds like a counterpart to the famous FizzBuzz problem.

Comment: Is it a school question? Why do you ask if you know the answer. Most ppl who knows it are not going to answer you.

Comment: Wrt your solution: `e1 > s2` is incorrect if `s1 > s2` as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`bool overlap = (s1 <= e2) && (s2 <= e1)`

Comment: Should be `<=` in both comparisons.

Comment: @Fred:  After this correction, this is obvoiusly the easiest and most efficient answer.  Surprising how many people don't get it right -- it really seems to be some kind of [FizzBuzz](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html).

Comment: This returns true for two events which are exactly adjacent but do not overlap.

Comment: @caf: If you don't consider that overlapping, you can replace "<=" with "<".

Comment: I finally figured out where I'd solved this problem before. I was writing code to determine if two aircraft had conflicting altitudes. Since the aircraft could be assigned block altitudes, each altitude could be a range. Any range overlap was a conflict.

Comment: @Fred, good thing you got it right! The `<=` would be very important in that application.

Comment: val s1 = 1
val s2 = 5
val e1 = 4
val e2 = 8

(s1 <= e2) && (s2 <= e1)

This returns false

Comment: @JianAstrero: That's correct. There's no overlap in the ranges 1-4 and 5-8.

Comment: how about this @FredLarson:
val s1 = 4
val s2 = 8
val e1 = 1
val e2 = 5

(s1 <= e2) && (s2 <= e1)

Comment: @JianAstrero: It won't work with the ranges backwards. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @FredLarson do you understand the question? dEtErMiNe If RaNgEs OvErLaP

Comment: @JianAstrero: Perhaps you are thinking the ranges are `(s1, s2)` and `(e1, e2)`. They're actually `(s1, e1)` and `(s2, e2)`.

Answer (score 8):

Fred's answer is both concise and correct.

I prefer:

```
bool overlap = !(e1 < s2 || e2 < s1);
```

I think this is clearer, but it is a very small difference.

Converted to english:

> They overlap if neither ends before the other starts.

---

This is similar to the overlapping rectangles problem. There are two good ways to write that test. They correspond to the statements:

> Two rectangles overlap if the left edge of both is to the left of the right edge of the other, and the top edge of both is above the bottom edge of the other.

> Two rectangles overlap if neither is to the left or above the other.

Answer (score 5):

They overlap if:

- `e1` between (inclusive of both endpoints) `s2` and `e2` **OR**
- `e2` between (inclusive of both endpoints) `s1` and `e1`

Answer (score 5):

This will also work:

```
max(s1, s2) < min(e1, e2)
```

Comment: Slick. I like this one the best.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
return s1 < s2 ? s2 <= e1 : s1 <= e2;
```

Comment: Unlike some of the other solutions, this one does not allow a compiler to optimize away the first branch.

Comment: @finnw: This compiles actually with the same number of branches as the solutions that use the short cutting boolean operators (|| or &&), although these could be changed to use the non sort cutting versions of these operators (| or &) which would then indeed result in less branching. But I agree that i.e. Fred Larsons new suggestion is more effecient than mine as it can either have a shorter code path in some cases or can be modified to have less branching if & is used instead of &&.

Comment: this is the kind of optimization I had in mind: http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax

Answer (score 1):

(S2-S1)<(e1-s1) || (S1-S2)<(e2-s2)

Comment: Any chance you could explain why this works? Helps the less clever like me to learn from you!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* return true if intervals overlap */
bool overlap(unsigned int s1, unsigned int e1, unsigned int s2, unsigned int e2) {
    return (s1 >= s2 && s1 <= e2) ||
            (e1 >= s2 && e1 <= e2) ||
            (s2 >= s1 && s2 <= e1) ||
            (e2 >= s1 && e2 <= e1);
}
```

Comment: This is nowhere near the most efficient solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(s2 < s1 && s1 < e2) || (s1 < s2 && s2 < e1)
```

or, equivalently:

```
(s2 < s1 && s1 < e2) || (s2 < e1 && e1 < e2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check In which cases It will not overlap

Condition for no overlap is :: (s2 > e1 ) || ( e2 > s1)
so overlap is !((s2 > e1 ) || ( e2 > s1))