# Meeting Conflict algorithms

Tags: algorithm, datetime, compare

I had a interview today and was asked to check whether two meeting conflicts with each other or not. Each meeting has start time and end time. 
I tried to answer the question but not that specific..can somebody throw some idea?

```
bool IsConflict(Datetime s1, Datetime e1, Datetime s2, Datetime e2)
```

should return true if Conflict is there and false if no conflict.

E.g

True if:
 
(s1, e1)= 8,10

(s2, e2) = 9, 11

(s1, e1)= 7,10

(s2, e2) = 8, 9

(s1, e1)= 8,11

(s2, e2) = 9, 11
and so on

Comment: I see [many language specific questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=overlapping+date+ranges) that would have helpful answers, but nothing general...

Comment: There really is nothing more to it that it looks like - just a few `if`s to see whether the dates overlap. Those `if`s could be streamlined and reduced in number if, for example, dates are sorted in a certain way (for instance based on their start, and after that - on their end).

Comment: This is just a variant of my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/comparing-date-ranges/143568#143568

Comment: The interviewer probably wanted to see how you solved the problem (I would draw a picture like Lasse did in his linked answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718004/tricky-interview-question

Answer (score 25):

This is basic interval algebra, see [my answer here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143552/comparing-date-ranges/143568#143568), but the code would look like this:

```
bool IsConflict(Datetime s1, Datetime e1, Datetime s2, Datetime e2)
{
    return (s1 < e2) && (e1 > s2);
}
```

I am assuming that two meetings where one start where the other ends are not in conflict.

Comment: Too bad it's community wiki, I think you deserve two upvotes per user for that linked answer.

Comment: No, I explicitly made it CW to avoid that, the question is in loose terms a duplicate, but enough different that it can stand on its own, but my answer would not be, hence CW.

Answer (score 2):

In the simple case of two intervals I think this will work (untested pseudocode ahead):

```
bool IsConflict(Datatime s1, Datatime e1, Datatime s2, Datatime e2) {
    if( s1 < s2 ) {
        // meeting 1 starts first
        if( e1 > s2 ) return true; // overlap
    }
    else {
        // meeting 2 starts first
        if( e2 > s1 ) return true; // overlap
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: While I agree Lasse's solution is more elegant, your solution is more easily understood IMHO

Answer (score 1):

The meetings overlap if and only if `max(s1, s2) < min(e1, e2)`. This intersection based approach assumes that intervals `(s, e)` are open, and implies (rightly or wrongly) that an *empty* meeting `s = e` cannot have an overlap with another meeting.

Answer (score 1):

Complexity of following algorithm is O (nlogn)

```
public boolean isConflicts(float startTime[], float endTime[])
{
    TreeMap<Float, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Float, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < startTime.length; i++)
    {
        map.put(startTime[i], -1);
        map.put(endTime[i], 1);
    }

    Iterator<Integer>iter = map.values().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        if ((iter.next() + iter.next()) != 0)
        {
             System.out.println ("Conflicts...");
             return true;
        }
    }
    return false;                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The plan**
There are three cases to check for with this problem.

- Case 1: Does s1 lie within the interval [s2,e2]
      (s1 >= s2) && (s1 <= e2)
- Case 2: Does e1 lie within the interval [s2, e2]
      (e1 >= s2) && (e2 <= e2))
- Case 3: Does the point (s2, e2) lie within [s1, e1]
      (s1 <= s2) && (e1 >= e2)

So here is the answer. I apologize; It's not the most readable lines of code.

**The code (pseudo):**

```
bool isConflict(Datetime s1, Datetime e1, Datetime s2, Datetime e2){
  return ((s1 >= s2) && (s1 <= e2)) || ((e1 >= s2) && (e2 <= e2)) || (s1 <= s2) && (e1 >= e2));
}
```